# Ajax script no funciona, no encuentro el error

Tags: php, ajax

No se que estoy haciendo mal , no encuentro el error y sin embargo no envía nada !!!
No se si es porque estoy poniendo
`dataType: 'json'` o porque , pero no esta enviando nada!
Mil gracias por la ayuda .

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var parametros = {
            "desdetrf" : $('#desdetrf').val(),
            "haciatrf" : $('#haciatrf').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url:'script.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#loading").show();
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                $("#loading").hide();         
                $("#unocontenidorespuesta1").html(response.contenidorespuesta1);
                $("#doscontenidorespuesta2").html(response.contenidorespuesta2);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿No envía o no recibe en el "success"? ¿Y qué pasa si quitas *dataType* de la llamada?

Comment: No envia ni recibe , ya que puse un echo en la primera linea de script.php con u exit(); para forzar a que retorne y nada tampoco , en cuanto al dataType ya lo quite y tampoco funciona!

Comment: Mira si se ejecuta algo del js. Si se ejecuta "beforeSend" de la llamada ajax. Modifica algo en el js para ver si llega a este punto. Si no llegas al servidor el problema debe estar en el cliente.

Comment: Acabo de imprimir los error y el error que tira es " parsererror "

Comment: Si, pero tendrá una línea donde se produce, mira ahí a ver qué es

Comment: No , solo me devuelve el tipo de error

Comment: Esto agregue entre otros tipos de errores
  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {
    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  }

Comment: trata de cambiar dataType: "text", para que puedas verificar si es error 200, porque se refiere a un error del propio JS, lo que se requiere un update.

Answer (score 0):

Probando tu codigo funciona perfectamente pero no sabras que pasa si no imprimes el error:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var parametros = {
            "desdetrf": $('#desdetrf').val(),
            "haciatrf": $('#haciatrf').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: 'script.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#loading").show();
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#loading").hide();
                $("#unocontenidorespuesta1").html(response.contenidorespuesta1);
                $("#doscontenidorespuesta2").html(response.contenidorespuesta2);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

En tu archivo script.php debes imprimir o retornar algo así:

```
 $cadena = array('uno','dos');
 echo json_encode($cadena); //esta es la clave codificar como json lo que recibes en tu ajax
```

Comment: Igmer , sigue sin funcionar , es mas copie exactamente lo tuyo y no imprime ningun error!

Comment: estas importando las librerias de jquery?

Comment: acabo de imprimir todos los errores  te muestro que devuelve cada uno

Comment: (xhr.statusText)= OK

Comment: devuelve el text de respuesta ( puse un echo "hola"seguido de un exit();

Comment: (xhr.status)=200

Comment: y por ultimo (thrownError)= syntaxError:JSON.parse.Error:Invalir character at position :1

Comment: porque espera un json pero estas imprimiendo una cadena

Comment: Te juro por mi vida que ahora funciona , y lo nico que hice fue agregar que me muestre el error , exactamente esto!
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
     alert(xhr.statusText); 
     alert(xhr.responseText); 
     alert(xhr.status); 
     alert(thrownError); 
    } ,

Comment: probe con todo el codigo de respuesta cuando me pusiste que tenia que devolver un json ( como lo tenia ) y no un echo para ver si llegaba algo , mil gracias por tu tiempo Igmer